# Sometimes boot and shutdown very slow

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown

It seems system jams at some point of boot and shutdown. This is Xubuntu 16.04. I would like to know more on what causes that slowness. Can you find something about it in logs? There are some huge log files:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -Slr --si | tail -n 15
```

outputs

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp  94k Aug 20 00:52 wtmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root 105k Apr 29 13:20 dpkg.log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  126k Aug 11 15:50 syslog.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  126k Aug 20 01:17 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  145k Aug 15 13:35 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root 177k May 16 18:21 boot.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root              utmp 293k Aug 17 00:21 lastlog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root 325k Aug 19 17:55 dpkg.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  503k Aug 15 13:33 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  1.8M Aug 20 00:56 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   23M Aug 19 17:17 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   29M Aug 18 08:57 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm   30M Aug 16 09:06 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  111M Aug 17 08:43 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm  3.4G Aug 20 01:22 kern.log
```

.

```
tail -55 /var/log/kern.log
```

outputs

```
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7132] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'jarnos-g' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7146] Config: added 'ssid' value 'jarnos-g'
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7152] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7158] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7165] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7169] Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7254] sup-iface[0xbcf770,wlp3s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Aug 21 11:58:13 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769893.7579] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.820883] wlp3s0: authenticate with dc:ee:06:95:dc:35
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.826426] wlp3s0: send auth to dc:ee:06:95:dc:35 (try 1/3)
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769896.8940] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.829337] wlp3s0: authenticated
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.832172] wlp3s0: associate with dc:ee:06:95:dc:35 (try 1/3)
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769896.9014] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.837510] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from dc:ee:06:95:dc:35 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.838865] wlp3s0: associated
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   31.838936] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
Aug 21 11:58:16 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769896.9109] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.0706] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.1881] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.1882] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'jarnos-g'.
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.1883] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.1916] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 21 11:58:17 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769897.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 2991
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.0710] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.0744] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 3050
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7838]   valid_lft 7200
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7838]   preferred_lft 3600
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7839]   address 2001:999:20:2495:dcee:695:dc35:3
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7839]   nameserver 'fe80::deee:6ff:fe95:dc35'
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7840] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound, event ID="de:02:e9:d5|1471769899"
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.7932] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8108] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8114] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8116] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8223] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8253] policy: set 'jarnos-g' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8302] DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <warn>  [1471769899.8403] dnsmasq[0xb9a340]: dnsmasq not found on the bus. The nameserver update will be sent when dnsmasq appears
Aug 21 11:58:19 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769899.8411] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.0405] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.0627] dnsmasq[0xb9a340]: dnsmasq appeared as :1.53
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.0636] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2825]   address 192.168.100.11
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2831]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2836]   gateway 192.168.100.1
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2841]   server identifier 192.168.100.1
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2845]   lease time 86400
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2849]   nameserver '192.168.100.1'
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2853]   nameserver '192.168.100.1'
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2853] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2969] policy: set 'jarnos-g' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 21 11:58:20 jarnos-3000-C200 NetworkManager[2253]: <info>  [1471769900.2978] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Aug 21 11:59:16 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [   92.000422] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4024.0004: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
Aug 21 12:00:03 jarnos-3000-C200 kernel: [  139.302544] perf interrupt took too long (2526 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

I tried to boot some older kernel and it tells:
"A start job is running for dev-mapper-cryptswap.device (18m 10s / no limit)"
And time keeps going on.

Comment: show us output of   tail -55 /var/log/kern.log
        ...   any log file that huge typically indicates some error or warning condition is getting printed repeatedly

Comment: @ScottStensland done

Answer (score 0):

For starters looks like you have enabled logging level of `info` which tells `NetworkManager` to spew tons of messages into the log which may be the cause of your multi gig kern.log ... here is the normal config file

```
cat  /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

as per http://linux.die.net/man/5/networkmanager.conf  just remove the portion of above config file for `[logging]` as per

```
[logging]
level=INFO
```

if infact your NetworkManager.conf does contain above mentioned `INFO`

As long as above `INFO` logging is active log is hard to read without tons of grepping so trim down log file as per

```
sudo -i
> /var/log/kern.log  # this line is correct the > says empty that file
exit
```

above empties the file without deleting it so the file descriptors remain intact to the writing process can continue unphased

Now reboot after doing above change to config file and emptying out file ... with logging set so high it may have slowed down your machine

Comment: The system already had the "normal" config file. Either "INFO" is the default value, or the value is given as `--log-level` option somewhere, which overrides the value mentioned  in the config file anyway.